# Facebook integration for implementing news feed and friend system

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I have one of my app already on appstore in which i have implemented facebook ios sdk 3.2 and i am using account framework for enabling facebook login to app.

Now i want to implement facebook friend system in which i want to invite all my friends and also want to show friends feed related to my app.

Whatever sample provided by Facebook are on different platform like opengraph and Graph APi and one sample i found using native integration.

My query here is that can i do all these things at ios side or i need to go for PHP backend facebook integration.

I am damn confuse here, Please provide me guideline on same, I want to do same as done in Foursquare app.Correct me if i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you already want to use the accounts framework so are you programming for ios 6 i guess so you dont need the facebook sdk. Ios 6 provides already everything for you to work with facebooks open graph. So you can import both the accounts framework together with the social framework. If you want some code about how to do so you should google or i would make some example codes tonight. From there you could do anything from your app that you could do with the PHP sdk. So you can use the examples provided by facebook to continue.

Comment: I am doing this only for ios 6, i have tried with sample sdk called friendPickerSample but i am not getting friend list with proper values. and plus i have to use FriendPicker class for this.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, i think i got solution to my question.

Please refer following URL:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/